# Order array of email addresses by frequency counts

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have an array with some duplicates. An efficient algorithm for sorting the array based on the duplicate count e.g.

```
['d@me.com', 'z@gmail.com', 'e@me.com', 'b@me.com', 'c@me.com', 'z@gmail.com', 'z@gmail.com', 'b@me.com', 'e@me.com']
=>
['z@gmail.com', 'e@me.com', 'b@me.com', 'd@me.com', 'c@me.com']
```

Because the counts are as followings `[3, 2, 2, 1, 1]`

I came up with:

```
const itemCounts = {}
const ordereditems = []
for (let i = 0; i < allitems.length; i++) {
  let item = allitems[i];
  itemCounts[item] = itemCounts[item] ? itemCounts[item] + 1 : 1
}
const tuples = []
for (let key in itemCounts) {
  tuples.push([key, itemCounts[key]])
}
return tuples.sort((a, b) => a[1] < b[1]).map(x => x[0])
```

Which is about `Θ(3 N + N log N)`?

Perhaps something faster with lodash?

Maybe keep a sorted priority queue as I do the counting?

Maybe use a radix sort of some kind?

Comment: Actually for input array size of `n`, this is at least log-linear (`O(n log n)`) since the tuples array can be up to `n` in length, and you're performing a general sort on it, which will be at least log-linear (most JS engines will implement a log-linear sort.)

Comment: Aside from constant factors, log-linear is the most efficient 'obvious' time-complexity for this algorithm (because the obvious way _must_ perform a sort). My intuition is that there's nothing clever you can do which would be significant enough to reduce the complexity class.

Comment: Actually it's about `3N + N log N ` which is why I put 4N but the question is, can I avoid looping the array 3 times and keep things sorted as I count the array?

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for updating the question. Surprisingly, I think I have a linear-time solution which I'll try to code up and post as an answer.

Comment: Will your array always contain just characters?

Comment: How many different things are in the input array?

Comment: @Dave probably hundreds. @ Said they are always strings (in this case emails)

Comment: What is the expected/greatest frequency of an item? What is the expected/greatest total number of items?

Comment: @גלעדברקן both of those would be in the hundreds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my try, and first attempt to write a snippet :)

```js
var allitems = ['d', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'e'];

function original_code(allitems) {
  const itemCounts = {}
  const ordereditems = []
  for (let i = 0; i < allitems.length; i++) {
    let item = allitems[i];
    itemCounts[item] = itemCounts[item] ? itemCounts[item] + 1 : 1
  }
  const tuples = []
  for (let key in itemCounts) {
    tuples.push([key, itemCounts[key]])
  }
  return tuples.sort((a, b) => a[1] < b[1]).map(x => x[0])
}

function myTry(allitems) {
  var arr;
  const dic = {};
  arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < allitems.length; i++) {
    let item = allitems[i];
    if (!dic.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
      dic[item] = 1;
      arr.push(item);
    } else
      dic[item]++;
  }
  arr.sort((a, b) => dic[b] - dic[a]);
  return arr;
}



//measure attempts
{ //original code
  var t0 = performance.now();
  var res;
  for (let j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
    res = original_code(allitems);
  }
  var t1 = performance.now();
  console.log("original " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
  console.log("original " + res);
}

{ //my try
  var t0 = performance.now();
  var res;
  for (let j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
    res = myTry(allitems);
  }
  var t1 = performance.now();
  console.log("myTry " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
  console.log("myTry " + res);
}



{ //my try
  var t0 = performance.now();
  var res;
  for (let j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
    res = myTry(allitems);
  }
  var t1 = performance.now();
  console.log("myTry2 " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
  console.log("myTry2 " + res);
}

{ //original code
  var t0 = performance.now();
  var res;
  for (let j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
    res = original_code(allitems);
  }
  var t1 = performance.now();
  console.log("original2 " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
  console.log("original2 " + res);
}
```

**Edit**
I've tried to make a more reliable measurement. If there is a better way, I'd appreciate if you tell me.

+
Changed the sorting.

Comment: Ah nice ! I don't have to create the tuple list I can just use the dict directly ! Didn't think of that

Comment: I'm not sure if I trust this performance measurement. I get inconsistent results, including the OP's code as running faster if I reverse the order of who's code runs first in the script.

Comment: @גלעד ברקן  Yes it is not reliable. Looping each for example 10000 times gives a more reliable measurement in my tests. But its not reliable still, I agree.

Comment: @david_adler I'm new to javascript and learned "let", "const" and "map" by your example, thank you for that..

Comment: Since you are new to JavaScript, note also that the sort compare function needs to return one of three: positive, negative or zero. This, `(a, b) => dic[a] < dic[b]` would not work. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @גלעדברקן  thank you very much. I've tried to correct it. Is it ok now?

Answer (score 1):

Use `array#reduce` to create a frequency object with word and frequency of this word in the array. Then based on the object value sort the values and then take out the all the words.

```js
var arr = ['d', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'e'],
    frequency = arr.reduce((r,val) => {
      r[val] = r[val] || {val, count : 0};
      r[val].count = r[val].count + 1;
      return r;
    },{});
var result = Object.values(frequency).sort((a,b) => {
  return b.count - a.count;
}).map(({val}) => val);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach will still have log-linear time complexity due to the sort operation.

Comment: Yes, it will have log-linear complexity of only unique words and not all the words.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't measured any times.
But here is an idea, using the filter function, to create a uniqueitems item array, and then uses that to zero fill the itemcounts array, thus removing the branch from the counting loop.

```js
const allitems= ['d', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'e'];
const itemCounts = {};
var uniqueitems = [];
var ordereditems = [];

// Filter out unique item list early
uniqueitems=allitems.filter( (v,i,s) => s.indexOf(v) === i );

// Set items counts of unique items to zero,
for (let i = 0; i < uniqueitems.length; i++) {
  let item = allitems[i];
  itemCounts[item] =0;
}

// Count occurences in allitems
for (let i = 0; i < allitems.length; i++) {
  let item = allitems[i];
  itemCounts[item]  ++;
}

// Sort unique items,directly based on their itemCount
ordereditems=uniqueitems.sort((a, b) => itemCounts[a] < itemCounts[b]);

console.log(ordereditems);
```

Answer (score 0):

I intuitively expected log-linear to be optimal for this algorithm specification, but in fact here's the gist of an (amortised) O(n) implementation I surprised myself by thinking of, using the magic of hash tables (Objects in JS)! It comes at the expense of taking more space. You need a doubly-linked list implementation. I'll hack one here but there are probably libraries better suited.

The `printList` function was for debugging, and could be useful if you're interested in going through how this works.

```js
function orderByCount(allitems) { // allitems is the array to be 'count-sorted'
  // linkedList will have at most one node per item. It will be used to build the result.
  // It will be ordered by count (seen so far) descending
  let linkedListHead = null
  let linkedListTail = null

  // if linkedList has a node for key k, itemIndex[k] is that node
  // if linkedList has no node for key k, itemIndex[k] is undefined
  let itemIndex = {}

  // for all x >= 1 if linkedList has a node with seen count <= x, countIndex[x] is the 'headmost' (first) node whose count <= x.
  // for all x >= 1 if linkedList has no node with seen count <= x, countIndex[x] is undefined
  let countIndex = {}

  // iterate over the input and maintain above invariants
  for (let i = 0; i < allitems.length; i++) {
    let item = allitems[i];

    if (itemIndex.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
      // we've already seen this item; update while preserving invariants
      const linkedNode = itemIndex[item]

      // first, remove the node, preserving invariants
      if (countIndex[linkedNode.count] === linkedNode) {
        countIndex[linkedNode.count] = linkedNode.next
      }
      if (linkedNode.previous) {
        linkedNode.previous.next = linkedNode.next
      } else {
        linkedListHead = linkedNode.next
      }
      if (linkedNode.next) {
        linkedNode.next.previous = linkedNode.previous
      } else {
        linkedListTail = linkedNode.previous
      }
      linkedNode.next = linkedNode.previous = null

      // now update the node
      linkedNode.count++

        // and add it back where it now belongs, preserving invariants
        if (countIndex.hasOwnProperty(linkedNode.count)) {
          // need to put it at the front of this count-block
          newNext = countIndex[linkedNode.count]
          newPrevious = newNext.previous
          linkedNode.next = newNext
          linkedNode.previous = newPrevious
          newNext.previous = linkedNode
          if (newPrevious) {
            newPrevious.next = linkedNode
          } else {
            linkedListHead = linkedNode
          }
          countIndex[linkedNode.count] = linkedNode
        } else {
          // it's the new greatest; create a new count-block
          countIndex[linkedNode.count] = linkedNode
          if (linkedListHead) {
            linkedListHead.previous = linkedNode
          }
          linkedNode.next = linkedListHead
          linkedListHead = linkedNode
        }
    } else {
      // this is a new item
      const linkedNode = {
        item: item,
        count: 1,
        previous: null,
        next: null
      }

      // First, insert it at the tail
      linkedNode.previous = linkedListTail
      if (linkedListTail) {
        linkedListTail.next = linkedNode
      }
      linkedListTail = linkedNode

      // now index it
      itemIndex[item] = linkedNode
      if (linkedListHead === null) {
        linkedListHead = linkedNode
      }
      if (!countIndex.hasOwnProperty(1)) {
        countIndex[1] = linkedNode
      }
    }
  }

  // turn it into a normal array as per specification 
  const result = []
  let current = linkedListHead
  while (current != null) {
    result.push(current.item)
    current = current.next
  }

  return result
}

function printList(linkedListHead, linkedListTail, countIndex) {
  let current = linkedListHead
  while (current != null) {
    toLog = JSON.stringify({
      item: current.item,
      count: current.count
    })
    if (linkedListHead === current) {
      toLog += " (HEAD)"
    }
    if (linkedListTail === current) {
      toLog += " (TAIL)"
    }
    if (countIndex[current.count] === current) {
      toLog += " <-- " + current.count
    }
    console.log(toLog)
    current = current.next
  }
  console.log()
}

const allItems = ['d', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'e']
console.log(orderByCount(allItems))
```

Comment: This could be made stable (in the sense that if two values have the same count, their output order is the same as the order they are first seen in the input) by making the `countIndex` point to the _end_ of each window, and putting values at the _back_ of each count-bucket. At the moment it does not have this property.

Comment: The same underlying algorithm could be used on streaming input of indeterminate size, in linear time and using at most linear space (assuming a good hash table implementation.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a better solution, using `arr.concat` instead of sort.

Notice that key in object is in order:

```js
const f = (allitems) => {
  const itemCounts = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < allitems.length; i++) {
    let item = allitems[i];
    itemCounts[item] = itemCounts[item] ? itemCounts[item] + 1 : 1
  }
  
  const map = {}
  for (let key in itemCounts) {
    const count = itemCounts[key]
    if(!map[count]) {
      map[count] = []
    }
    map[count].push(key)
  }
  
  let ordereditems = []
  for (let key in map) {
    ordereditems = ordereditems.concat(map[key])
  }
  return ordereditems.reverse()
}
console.log(f(['d', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'e']))
```

Not much test cases for this, so it may not be much robust.

Answer (score -1):

```
['d', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'e'].sort((x,y)=> x.charCodeAt()-y.charCodeAt())
```

Comment: i do not think this is OP expect

Comment: Read the question properly

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!